# Как выключить скролл страницы у fullpage.js при движении ползунка input range?

Tags: javascript, fullpage, fullpage.js

Когда я на телефоне двигаю ползунок, то у меня срабатывает скролл от fullpage.js
Как пофиксить? Помогите!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуй в обработчике события твоего скролла, сделать `e.stopPropagation()`. Вероятно fullpage.js подписан на событие скроллина, которое возникает в body. Туда же попадает события от твоего скролла. Подробнее тут: https://medium.com/@vsvaibhav2016/event-bubbling-and-event-capturing-in-javascript-6ff38bec30e и тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387736/how-to-stop-event-propagation-with-inline-onclick-attribute и здесь https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/event_stoppropagation.asp

Comment: @Daniel не совсем понял.. Объясни, пожалуйста, что за обработчик скролла?

Comment: Обработчик события скролла - функция, которая реагирует на oninput. Ты ведь как-то хендлишь изменения input range. Вот в этой функции напиши e.stopPropagation(). По возможности прикрепи код html, js для своего скролла к вопросу. А еще лучше, залей его на codepen